# Given some sequence of set $A_k$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, A_n \subset B \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ then, $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_n$ be some sequence of set. My textbook says,

> $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, A_n \subset B \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$, then $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k = B$.

I'd like to ask why this holds.

In my opinion, if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, A_n \subset B \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ holds, then $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}B = B$. This leads to the following strange situation

$\ldots \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \subset B \subset \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k \subset B \ldots$

And, this never be leads to $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = B$. (If $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$ then the statement holds I think)

Comment: Your textbook must use $\subset$ to mean "subset, possibly equal but not necessarily", and not to mean "proper inclusion". Review their conventions, because if $\subset$ means $\subsetneq$ (proper inclusion), then the statement is only true because the premise can never hold.

Comment: Well, if there is some element $\alpha$ in the union but not in $B$, then $\alpha\in A_m$ for some $m$, leading to a contradiction.  Note: I am assuming that "$\subset$" allows for equality here, otherwise the claim does not make sense.

Comment: It may be an issue of which conventions the book is using.

Some people use $\subset$  for proper subset or equal and $\subsetneq$ for proper subset; some people use $\subseteq$ for proper subset or equal and $\subset$ for proper subset.

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, you have $B\subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$.

Now, take $x \in\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$. Then there exists $n$ such that $x\in A_n$. But $A_n\subset B$, then $x\in B$ and therefore $\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\subset B$. So they are equal.

But if you are using $\subset$ as proper inclusion, then it is false, since $B\subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ would imply $B\neq \cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$